# Removing a penny raises mean coin value from 17 to 18. How many nickles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So this is a question that my sister (grade 8) got wrong on a test.

> There is a collection of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies in a jar. The mean of these coins is 17 but when you remove a penny, the mean becomes 18.
>
> How many nickels are in the jar?

I tried to get the multiple of $17$ which subtracted by $1$ and divided by $16$ is $18$.

For that I got $17 \cdot 17 = 289 - 1 = 288 / 16 = 18$ which is correct.

The only problem that I'm encountering is which coins are in the collection and of course how many nickels are there.

Comment: What’s “the mean”?

Comment: @LucasHenrique the average value

Comment: the mean value of coin.  (Coins are worth 1,5,10,25 cents for non-americans)

Answer (score 4):

You got most of the way there already. You know there are 16 coins that are worth a total of 288 cents. Three of these must be pennies (since 288 is 3 mod 5 and all non-pennies have value 0 mod 5), so that leaves 13 worth 285.

This can be achieved with 11 quarters and 2 nickels.

In a jar with $Q$ quarters and $13-Q$ other coins, for $Q\leq10$, the total value of the jar is at most $25Q+10(13-Q)=130+15Q\leq280<285$ cents, so you need at least 11 quarters. However, with 11 quarters, you have ten cents left and 2 coins, so they must both be nickels.

Comment: Yeah that's the answer I got as well but since it said that the collection includes dimes as well I didn't know if it would be correct without dimes